# C++ call to deleted constructor. Understanding pointers vectors and for loops

Tags: c++, vector, cocos2d-x

I am getting struggling a little bit to understand c++. I am using cocos2dx and trying to make an vector of sprites (bricks) that will be for a [breakout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)) game. I am able to add a bunch of sprites into the vector (atleast I think I am loading them into the vector), but when I try to iterate over the vector and read them I am getting an error: "Call to deleted constructor of 'cocos2d::Sprite'". I thought I understood pointers but can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong and what's going on with this snippet?

```
std::vector<Sprite> sprites;
brick = Sprite::create("brick.png");
for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
    Sprite *sprite = Sprite::create("brick.png");
    sprites.push_back(*sprite);
    this->addChild(sprite);
}
for (int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++){
    Sprite sprite = sprites[i]; //Call to deleted constructor of 'cocos2d::Sprite'
}
```

Comment: Are `Sprites` safely copyable and assignable?  Your problem probably has nothing really to do with `vector`, but with copy and assignment of `Sprite` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem

There are a number of things wrong with the code you've posted. I'll start at the top:

```
std::vector<Sprite> sprites;
```

This is declaring a vector of type **objects**, not pointers.

This is problematic because this line:

```
Sprite::create("brick.png");
```

Returns a **pointer** to a `Sprite` object, but you are doing this to add it to the list:

```
sprites.push_back(*sprite);
```

The `*` out front of `sprite` means that this is what's called a de-referencing of a pointer type. This essentially creates a copy (using the copy constructor) of the already extant `sprite` (using `Sprite`'s copy constructor.

The reason the object is being deleted here:

```
Sprite sprite = sprites[i];
```

Is because you are creating a local copy of the sprite in `sprite[i]`, and then immediately deleting it after each iteration of the loop (because it's falling out of scope).

## Solution

The best way to fix this is to change the definition of your sprite vector to:

```
std::vector<Sprite*> sprites;
```

And deal *only* with the pointers.

You can then change this line:

```
sprites.push_back(*sprite);
```

to:

```
sprites.push_back(sprite);
```

And this line:

```
Sprite sprite = sprites[i];
```

to:

```
Sprite* sprite = sprites[i];
```